# Why dosent fruit get assigned 'apple' in this generator function?

Tags: javascript, generator

Title says it all.

Output is:

```
starting
lol
undefined
0 undefined
```

Expected:

```
starting // yield giving us back a string
lol  // yield giving back result from bar()
'apples' // since the 'yield bar()' is 'replaced' by 'apples' via next('apples')
'0 apples' // the last yield should tell us what fruit is, but its undefined
```

Code:

```js
const bar = () => 'lol'

function* foo1() {
  yield 'starting'
  let a = 0
  let fruit = yield bar()
  console.log(fruit) // <-- y no apples? I could even see 'lol' being here too.
  yield `${a} ${fruit}`

}

let g = foo1()

console.log(g.next().value)
console.log(g.next('apples').value)
console.log(g.next().value)
```

Comment: Generators are initially paused. The first `next` starts them.

Comment: I see that two people understood your comment, but it doesn't seem obvious to me.

Comment: Why the downvote people? There's running code, expected output....

Comment: @jason No it's not,  downvotes are intended to point out that a question is poorly asked. This question fulfills all the requirements. No need to bash SO because you got downvoted a few times :D However, yes, if you're going to downvote, a comment is often helpful so the OP or the person replying can improve their question/answerq

Comment: @jason Do you feel like the single answer to the top duplicate doesn’t directly answer your question (and more than that, with a question asking about the exact problem)?

Comment: It does not. I do start off the generator with a next().

Comment: Im trying to decipher your meaning though, the 'initially paused' part.

Comment: @Ry I also don't see it, I think an answer explaining what's going on here would be helpful, even to seasoned developers

Comment: @jason: And then you pause it again with a `yield 'starting'`. If you already knew about the behaviour it’s just an error of counting. The third call to `next` corresponds to the second `yield`.

Comment: Possibly, but I think maybe I dont understand passing in stuff via next('stuff').

Comment: Try passing in a separate value with every `next` call and it might be a bit clearer. `g.next('a').value`, `g.next('b').value`, `g.next('c').value`

Comment: Ahhhh i see. tytyty

Comment: 1, `.next()` unpauses the generator, runs `yield 'starting', pauses. 2. `.next('apples')` unpauses the generator, runs `yield bar()`, pauses. 3. `.next()` unpauses the generator *runs the assignment*...

Comment: Yep. VLAZ for the win.

Comment: For anyone finding this, move the 'apples' to the next next() statement, and it all works as intended. The part I was missing (that Ry and VLAZ educated me on) was that the yield pauses BEFORE it assigns to fruit. Meditate on that and it all comes together. Thanks yall. :)

Answer (score -1):

According to [Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*#passing_arguments_into_generators) **function***

> // the first call of next executes from the start of the function until the first yield statement

You must 'init' with a first `next()` call before getting yield statement

```js
const bar = () => 'lol'

function* foo1() {  
  yield 'starting'
  let a = 0
  let fruit = yield bar()
  console.log(fruit)  // <-- y no apples? I could even see 'lol' being here too.
  yield `${a} ${fruit}`
  
}

let g = foo1()
g.next();
console.log( g.next().value)
console.log( g.next('apples').value )
```

Comment: An answer should have an English explanation, not just code

Comment: the first call of next executes from the start of the function until the first yield statement is an explenation... But answer edited